# Get the text margins of a QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

How can I get the text margins for a QLineEdit?

Note the red lines in the screenshot, that's the margins I'm interested in:

[image]

I tried `qDebug() << ui->lineEdit->textMargins();` for the edit box from the screenshot, but it printed `QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`, even though the edit box does have margins.

Comment: Eventually this is the space between font-size and widget-size? You probably could calculate this by size of font (QFontMetrics) and the available height. The textMargins() method returns the reserved free space for margins, a margin of 0 does not imply your font will always hit the borders.

Comment: That could account for the vertical margins, but not for the horizontal one. Also, the horizontal one can disappear, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/9mD13.png

Comment: Why do you need this information? maybe there is alternative way to solve your problem without getting this values.

Comment: @MarekR I need to calculate the absolute bounding box of a given character. Why do I need that? Long story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [paint event of QLineEdit](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qlineedit.cpp?h=v5.13.0#n1933). As you can see lots of stuff have effect on it.

Besides `textMargins` there are stuff which can have impact on values which you are looking for.

1. used style (see line 1942)
2. and font properties - see [QFontMetrics::ascent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#ascent) and [QFontMetrics::descent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#descent)

The style value is most important and you have to find way to get this value (probably subclass is needed).